# filter some child object without nested

Tags: elasticsearch

I want match both fields in same child `{ sale: true, name: "book1" }`, but ES give all separate matching data, this is documents:

```
[
  {
    "store": "storeA",
    "books": [
      { // should only matched
        "sale": true,
        "name": "book1",
        "price": 2,
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "store": "storeB",
    "books": [
      {
        "sale": false,
        "name": "book1",
        "price": 2,
      },
      {
        "sale": true,
        "name": "book2",
        "price": 3,
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

This is query, results should only be one `storeA`, but got two stores.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [ 
                { "match": { sale: true } },
                { "match": { name: "book1" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can give me some suggesting ?
Sorry the `books` field is not `nested` type, and I can't change that mapping type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation for the same, as below:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "stores" : {
            "filter" : { "term": { "sale": true } },
            "aggs" : { "term" : { "name" : "book1" } }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you. Or you can take reference from :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation

Comment: thanks buddy, It's query in different sub-object, not I except.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `name` of type `keyword` you can make use of the below [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

If its text and you *do not have its* keyword twin(`name.keyword`), then I'm afraid you would need to introduce its [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) of type `keyword` for below query to work. (Mapping change)

You can also have `"fielddata":true` for existing `book` field but firstly it is not recommended, and then again it would require updating the mapping.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
             "script": """
                if(doc['books.name'].value=="book1" && doc['books.sale'].value==true) 
                  return true;
                """      
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: thanks buddy, It seems that didn't query at the single sub-object, finally I got around this difficulty. thank you very much.

Comment: hey @joaner, I'm glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer ;-)